# Total number of instructions executed in MIPS code?

Tags: mips, instructions

In this MIPS program

When this code fragment is run, how many instructions will be executed in total?

```
i1: ori $t0, $0, 1000
i2: ori $t1, $0, 2000
i3: addi $t2, $t0, 100
i4: lw $t3, 0($t1)
i5: lw $t4, 0($t0)
i6: add $t3, $t3, $t4
i7: sra $t3, $t3, 1
i8: sw $t3, 0($t0)
i9: sw $t3, 0($t1)
i10: addi $t0, $t0, 4
i11: addi $t1, $t1, 4
i12: slt $t3, $t0, $t2
i13: bne $0, $t3, i4
```

Answer (score 0):

On every cycle, it adds 4 to $t0, which is initialized to 1000. At the end of the cycle, it checks if $t0 is greater than $t2, which is initialized to 1100. If it is, then the cycle breaks. So, it's the original 13 instructions, plus 10 for every cycle until it breaks. And it cycles an additional 25 times. And I may have added wrong, but if not, it's 263 instructions.

Comment: It's 253. 25 loops of 10 instructions, plus an addition 3 for the first cycle.

Comment: No it doesn't break until $t0 is greater than $t2, not equal to. It cycles 26 full times, 13 for the first cycle, 10 for the rest.

Comment: It breaks when they are equal. It's `slt`, not `sle`. Run the test yourself: https://gist.github.com/2572845

Comment: Depends on whether you count pseudo-instructions as a single instruction or their individual pieces, in which case you can look at a debugger and count the bytes (every instruction takes up 4 bytes, pseudo instructions take up more but it's always a multiple of 4)